# TypedArray copy to TypedArray

Tags: java, android

how you could copy a TypedArray to another TypedArray?

For example:

TypedArray "A" containing 5 values.
Copy values ​​1, 3, 5 to TypedArray "B"

```
TypedArray sonA;
TypedArray sonB;


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    if (i==0) or (i==2) or (i==4) {

     //what to do????
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show TypedArray source code ?

Comment: `sonA = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.items_son_sella);`